# J how to make a shape of random numbers

Tags: list, j

I'm trying to make a shape of random numbers (0 or 1) in this case as I'm trying to create a minesweeper field.

I've tried using the "?" symbol for random to receive it but it normally turns into an unrandom, repeated pattern which for my purposes is unsatisfactory:

```
5 5 $ ? 0 1

0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

Because of this, I tried other ways like pulling numbers from an index (this is called roll). But this returns random decimals. Other small changes to the code also resulted in these random decimals.

Comment: bob's answer below answers your current question. If you haven't seen it already the minesweeper implementation in the J Application Library may be of interest:  https://github.com/jsoftware/games_minesweeper/blob/master/minefield.ijs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this a few times myself. The key thing is when you apply the `?`. You get the result that you want if you apply it after the matrix has been created.

We know that `?2` returns a `1` or a `0` value generated randomly.

```
   ? 2
0
   ? 2
1
   ? 2
0
```

So if we create a 5X5 matrix of `2`'s

```
   5 5 $ 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
```

then we apply `?` to each `2` in the matrix you get the random `1` or `0` for each position.

```
   ? 5 5 $ 2 NB. first 5 X 5 matrix of random 1's and 0's
0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 0

   ? 5 5 $ 2  NB. different 5 X 5 matrix of random 1's and 0's
0 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: I spent 30 minutes trying and it was this simple... Well, I still don't understand why it's the way it is but it works so thanks.

Comment: There’s also special, faster code for `x ?@$ y`, and even more especially when `y=2`.